# How to make Eclipse Debug Output always show latest output lines

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging my PHP application, trying to see what HTML code is being generated while I trace through the code.

Problem is, everytime the Debug Output window fills its window, it scrolls to the top, forcing me to scroll down to view the last few HTML lines generated.

Is there a way to make Debug Output not scroll up ?

The effect I'm after is like doing a tail -f on a changing file - I always see the last lines added.

Hope there is a solution out there.

Comment: The behavior you're looking for is the default behavior... at least in all my experience with Eclipse.

Comment: I supposed you meant it scrolled up since the scroll is locked, but if that's not what's happening then it's an unexpected behavior. I wouldn't really know what's happening then, since as Dolph says, what you're looking for is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse Console view, check the "Scroll Lock" button. It should be unchecked for the Output to be the latest.

Comment: The OP says the console scrolls UP when there's output... that doesn't sound like the console's Scroll Lock is enabled to me.

Comment: The article on http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53574.html is suggesting the same thing. But will clicking on the Scroll Lock button affect the Debut Output window (which doesn't have its own Scroll Lock button) ? Is there a way to redirect output from the Debug Output window to the Console window ?